# Как вернуться на главную страницу сайта после открытия "send.php"?

Tags: php

Есть у меня файл на php который отправляет данные, введённые в формах на сайте в текстовый файл.

```
<form action="send.php" method=post> 
<p>Оформить заказ <p> 
<div align="center"> 
Имя<br/> 
<input type="text" name="name" size="40" required placeholder="Иван"><br /> 
Номер телефона<br /> 
<input type="text" name="title" size="40" required placeholder="+380 949494201"><br /> 
Заказ<br /> 
<textarea name="mess" rows="10" cols="40" required></textarea> 
<br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="submit" required></div> 
</form>
```

после нажатия кнопки "отправить" данные из всех трёх форм оправляются в файл, а как вернутся на главную страницу после перехода на php файл?
Вот сам "send.php"

```
<?php
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "a+");
fwrite($f, $_POST["name"]."\r\n"); 
fwrite($f, $_POST["title"]."\r\n"); 
fwrite($f, $_POST["mess"]."\r\n"); 
fwrite($f, "-------------------"."\r\n"); 
fclose($f);
fclose($f);
fclose($f);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: Насколько помню, в конец файла нужно добавить header("Location: url страницы");
А еще можно отправлять данные в send.php через $.ajax, если вариант на js приемлем - тогда страница вообще не будет перезагружаться

Comment: @Cheg, в header куда? Можно код пожалуйста? просто только начинаю... pleeeeeease

Comment: Можно в `echo` вывести `js-script`. `window.location.href = index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "a+");
  fwrite($f, $_POST["name"]."\r\n".$_POST["title"]."\r\n".$_POST["mess"]."\r\n");
  fwrite($f, "-------------------"."\r\n");
  fclose($f);
  header("Location: index.php");
?>
```